# angularjs data not posting from javascript to C# and also service reference not connecting

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two problems.  1 is that the c# function does not get the js values.  Even though when I step through the javascript, the values are in fact there.

The other problem is that my c#  post returns a 404 not found error and I see that the debugger never even goes to my other service on localhost123.

Any advice?

This is my angularjs code below

```
 var AddToGroupIds = [];
            var RemoveFromGroupIds = [];
            angular.forEach($scope.vm.mailingLists, function(f){
                if(f.Selected == true){
                    AddToGroupIds.push(f.Id);
            }
            else{
                RemoveFromGroupIds.push(f.Id);
        }
    });
 return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Contacts/UpdateSubscription',          
        data: { AddToGroups: AddToGroupIds, RemoveFromGroups: RemoveFromGroupIds, email: 'test@test.com' }
    })
        .then(function (data) { return data.data; })

this is my c# code below:

 [HttpPost]
 public void UpdateSubscription(List<int> AddToGroups, List<int> RemoveFromGroups, string email)
        {           
            HttpWebRequest req = null;
            var text = "";
            try
            {
               req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(string.Format("http://localhost:123/api/Api/ImmediateUpload?AddToGroupIds={0}&RemoveFromGroupIds={1}&email={2}", AddToGroups, RemoveFromGroups, email));
               req.PreAuthenticate = true;
               req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("123", "123", "123");

                var res = req.GetResponse();

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
                res.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                text = e.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Comment: 1.)Would be nice to see your routing as well.
2.)What you could try is to create a viewmodel in C# that reflects your JS model exactly.
3.) Try to test your api with Postman in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot post multiple parameters that way. See [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods). You can use JObject as the article mentions, or create a UpdateSubscriptionRequest model containing the parameters:

```
public class UpdateSubscriptionRequest
{
     public List<int> AddToGroups { get; set; }
     public List<int> RemoveFromGroups { get; set;}
     public string Email { get; set;}
}
```

And change your controller action to:

```
public void UpdateSubscription([FromBody]UpdateSubscriptionRequest request)
```

Comment: He also got a routing problem.

Comment: @nodes  that worked!  any suggestions for why my request isn't going to my localhost service?